# Make MVC URL same as old ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website developed in dot net 2.0 I need to update that in to MVC framework. How to keep my old URLs same in MVC? For eg. `WWW.something.com/Home.aspx` and `WWW.something.com/About.aspx`. I need to keep this URL structure. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MVC routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) to make your URLs the same as your old site.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Home",
        url: "Home.aspx",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "About",
        url: "About.aspx",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Note that in MVC 5 you could use [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) as an alternative to putting every route in the shared RegisterRoutes method.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // Important: Put this before your default route
    // or attribute routing won't work.
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Home.aspx", Name = "Home")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("About.aspx", Name = "About")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be just to use the new URL scheme and use the [IIS rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to configure 301 redirects from your old URL locations to your new ones so you don't lose any traffic and all of your old hyperlinks will still work.